# Implementing Popback in doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I was able to make pop_front function for doubly link list that utilizes head and tail. But when I was approach similar way to create pop_back function, it looks like there is nothing happening from the outcome.

I am trying to utilize tail without traversing entire list. so I create temp pointer that points to tail and started from there.  Is there something I am missing in pop_front function in logic?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//Create doubly Link List

struct node {
    int data;
    node* next, *prev;
};



class link {
    node *head, *tail;
public:
    link() { head =nullptr; tail = nullptr; }
    ~link(){}

    node *getnewnode(int data) {
        node* curr = new node;
        curr->data = data;
        curr->next = curr->prev = nullptr;
        return curr;
    }
    node *pushfront(int data) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            return head=tail=getnewnode(data);
        }
        node* curr = getnewnode(data);

        head->prev = curr; 
        curr->next = head;
        head = curr;
        return head;
    }
    node *pushback(int data) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            return head =tail= getnewnode(data);
        }
        node* curr = getnewnode(data);
        curr->prev= tail;
        tail->next = curr;
        tail = curr;
        return head;
    }
    node* popfront() {
        if (head == nullptr)
            return head;
        node*curr = head;
        head = head->next;
        head->prev = head->next->prev;
        delete curr;
        return head;
    }
    node *popback() {
        if (head= nullptr)
            return head;
        node*curr = tail;
        tail = tail->prev;
        //tail->prev->next = nullptr; //it did not work
        delete curr;
        return head;
    }
    void print() {
        while (head) {
            cout << head->data << endl;
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    link test;







    cout << "\n" << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        test.pushfront(i);
    cout << "after this pushfront:" << endl;
    //test.print();

    //test.popfront();
    //test.popfront();
    //test.popfront();

    test.popback();
    test.popback();
    test.popback();
    cout << "after this popback:" << endl;



    /*
    cout << "after this pushback:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        test.pushback(i);
    */
        test.print();

}
```

Comment: Do not ignore the compiler warnings. They are the first line of defense against errors like this. A compiler error means the code is syntactically incorrect and cannot be converted into a executable code. A compiler warning means the code is syntactically correct, but probably logically incorrect. Wanting to assign a value in a conditional statement is so rare that compilers call it out when found.

Comment: I actually manage to solve it. node *popback() {
  
  node *curr, *prevcurr;
  if (head == nullptr)
   return head;
  if (head->next == nullptr) {
   curr = head;
   head = nullptr;
   delete curr;
   return head;
  }
  else{
  curr = tail;
  prevcurr = tail->prev;
  tail = prevcurr;
  tail->next = nullptr;
  delete curr;
  return head;
  }

 }

Comment: When popping the last node in the list, that implementation is not updating `tail` to `nullptr` when setting `head` to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `popfront()` is implemented wrong, which is probably what is confusing you about implementing `popback()`.

`popfront()` is setting the new `head`'s `prev` to point back to the new `head` instead of to `nullptr` (since the new `head` is now the 1st node in the list). And if the list only has 1 node at the time of the pop, `tail` is not being updated to `nullptr`, but more importantly trying to set `head->prev` will fail since `head` is now `nullptr`.

In `popback()`, `if (head= nullptr)` is using the assignment `operator=` instead of the comparison `operator==`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
node* popfront() {
    if (head == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    node *curr = head;
    head = curr->next;
    if (head)
        head->prev = nullptr;
    if (curr == tail)
        tail = nullptr;
    delete curr;
    return head;
}

node *popback() {
    if (tail == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    node *curr = tail;
    tail = curr->prev;
    if (tail)
        tail->next = nullptr;
    if (curr == head)
        head = nullptr;
    delete curr;
    return head;
}
```

Also, `print()` is implemented wrong, too.  It is modifying `head` when it should not be.  Use a local pointer instead, like you do in `popfront()` and `popback()`:

```
void print() {
    node *curr = head;
    while (curr) {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```